# Display SectionList from API data in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I'm trying to create a SectionList from data received from an API. This API has the following structure for the ingredients that I want to display:

```
const ingredients = {
    malt: [
      {
        name: 'Maris Otter Extra Pale',
        amount: {
          value: 3.3,
          unit: 'kilograms',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Caramalt',
        amount: {
          value: 0.2,
          unit: 'kilograms',
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Munich',
        amount: {
          value: 0.4,
          unit: 'kilograms',
        },
      },
    ],
    hops: [
      {
        name: 'Fuggles',
        amount: {
          value: 25,
          unit: 'grams',
        },
        add: 'start',
        attribute: 'bitter',
      },
      {
        name: 'First Gold',
        amount: {
          value: 25,
          unit: 'grams',
        },
        add: 'start',
        attribute: 'bitter',
      },
      {
        name: 'Fuggles',
        amount: {
          value: 37.5,
          unit: 'grams',
        },
        add: 'middle',
        attribute: 'flavour',
      },
      {
        name: 'First Gold',
        amount: {
          value: 37.5,
          unit: 'grams',
        },
        add: 'middle',
        attribute: 'flavour',
      },
      {
        name: 'Cascade',
        amount: {
          value: 37.5,
          unit: 'grams',
        },
        add: 'end',
        attribute: 'flavour',
      },
    ],
    yeast: 'Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™',
  };
```

The desired result is the following using SectionList (with malt and hops as section headers):

[Visual example of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l1th.png)

I've already tried to use functions like Object.values(), with no result at all. The code simply looks like the following, receiving the beer from the previous view(with a beer list):

```
const Detail = ({ route }) => {
  const beer = route.params.beer;
  const ingredientsFormatted = Object.values(beer.ingredients);
  return(
  <SectionList
    sections={ingredientsFormatted}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>; //Here there has to be the name of the different ingredients
        }}
        renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => <Text>{section}</Text>} //Here there has to be malt, hops or yeast
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
      ></SectionList>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your `ingredients` data.

1. Format in value for `yeast` is not the same as the others.
2. Your data inserted into SectionList is not the format recommended by [React-Native Offical docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist).

To fix this, you can modify your API return / map the data after retrieved from server.

```
const Detail = ({ route }) => {
  const beer = route.params.beer;
  let sectionListTemplate = [];

  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(beer.ingredients)) {
    //console.log(`${key}: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);

    if(!Array.isArray(value)){
      //Handle case for 'yeast' which its data is not an array
      sectionListTemplate.push({
        title: key,
        data: [{
          name: value
        }]
      })
    }
    else{
      //Map value for general cases
      sectionListTemplate.push({
        title: key,
        data: value
      })
    }
  }

  return(
    <SectionList
      sections={sectionListTemplate}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => {
        return(
          //Here there has to be malt, hops or yeast
          <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}> 
            {section.title}
          </Text>
        )
      }} 
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return(
          //Here there has to be the name of the different ingredients
          <Text>
            {item.name}
          </Text> 
        )
      }}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
    >
    </SectionList>
  )
)}
```

Comment: This code works good, but I can only show the section headers, not the items in renderItem. I found out that the name of the ingredients must be unique, which I have adapted. Since I'm only saving the unique names of the ingredients, they still aren't rendered. Any clue what the problem is? @PeterTam

Comment: If you are talking about your `renderItem` in your question is not rendering anything, the reason is that you passed a function to it `{}` however you don't return anything. Therefore the list items are not showing. The solution is to add `return` before your `<Text>{item.name}</Text>` JSX or use `({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>` instead.